# B-Movie identification: tunnel under the Pacific ocean

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

This movie has been running around in my head long enough, using up valuable brain cycles.

It would have been shown as a Saturday morning movie in the UK, circa '80s.

Villians were Chinese and were tunneling under the Pacific. From what little I can remember I believe it was some form of invasion. Sorry for so little information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is surely *[Battle Beneath the Earth](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0061387/?ref_=tt_urv)*, a cheesy B-movie from 1967. According to the plot summary on IMDB:

> A Chinese general goes berserk and has a system of tunnels dug all the
> way from China to USA, under the Pacific Ocean. The man who has
> discovered this is locked up because they think he is insane. US Navy
> soldiers go underground to repel the invaders.

Comment: My primary school used to show us a movie every Friday afternoon, presumably for not burning the school down during the week, because I can't imagine we did anything else to deserve it.  That was one I remember.  Nothing quite makes a B-movie fun like a school full of kids eating more-or-less 100% sugar while it's on.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine - Weird that they'd punish you so harshly for *not* burning the school down, but schools do weird things sometimes. Not my school, not my place to judge.

Comment: @T.E.D. Our school had these insanely huge windows which were repeatedly broken by local vandals exploring structural mechanics.  Someone had the bright idea of using huge panes of very strongly plastic.  No more breaks.  They then tried to burn the windows.  They didn't burn or break but they warped one heck of a lot making the view way more interesting.  So, who knows, maybe we were being rewarded for not burning the place down ?  It was, however, a terrible shock later discovering secondary school didn't show movies at all, even B-movies.

Comment: OP and Clara: was that the one where a deep mine accidentally broke into a Chinese tunnel, and at the end the antagonist sat down next to one of his own armed nukes waiting for it to explode? I think I remember seeing it on British TV in the late 70s.

Comment: Checked the trailer on imdb and as soon as the mad scientist appeared raving on the screen I knew it was the same film. Glad I've got those brain cycles back, thanks.

Comment: @MatthewReece-Ford Humorously, you decided that there might indeed be two different B movies involving the Chinese making a tunnel under the Pacific Ocean, and I don't find that unreasonable at all.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Yes, that's the one. The deep mine was in "Oregon" (the actual filming location was somewhere in SE England), and the antagonist, the evil Chinese general, was trying to defuse the bomb that the American hero had rigged to go off, realised he couldn't, and just sat quietly next to it as it counted-down and exploded.